# MySQL crash with error 23

Tags: mysql

While loading a batch of data into a MySQL database (everything running locally for data management for a research project), the server crashed for no obvious reason. Examination of the logs showed the following errors:

```
ERROR, InnoDB: Operating system error number 23 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
ERROR, InnoDB: File .\analysis_lastfm\lastfm_scrobbles.ibd: 'Windows aio' returned 
   OS error 123. Cannot continue operation
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

This basically seemed to say that, somehow, the named .ibd file had become corrupted. After various unsuccessful debugging attempts, I finally deleted all my data, reinstalled MySQL, and tried restoring from a backup. This backup was from well before I had had any problems (in other words, it seems doubtful that there's anything wrong with data in the backup). All the other tables restored fine, but after a couple of hours importing data from the lastfm_scrobbles table, the server crashed with the same error.

I realize this question isn't as specific as it could be, but I'm mainly trying to figure out what my next troubleshooting steps should be (keeping in mind I've already reinstalled MySQL and attempted to restore from backup). The only other idea I have at this point is reformatting the hard drive and reattempting the restore, but I don't know if that's really warranted at this point...

Comment: Try importing from the lastfm_scrobbles table in smaller batches.  It sounds like there may be an issue with that particular table or data there in.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable idea, but the backup I'm importing now is from before I ever had any issues, so it seems pretty unlikely (though not impossible) that there's corruption in the backup...

Answer (score 0):

Given it seems the issue is probably not corruption, most likely the error is that the system has too many files open.  This issue is not as well understood/documented on Windows as it is on Linux.

It may help to reduce the table_open_cache and innodb_open_files variables down smaller.  If you can report their current size we may be able to recommend better values but it seems the total open file count may need to be under 512-2048 (Not sure exactly which).

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%open%';

Comment: Well, since the crash the server won't start so I can't run the query you've suggested, but my config tells me that innodb_open_files = 300. I don't see anything in the config file that says table_open_cache, though...

Comment: hi, did you figured it out? can you share your experience? I am facing same error and looking to see what other did to overcome it; it seems the table is corrupted, is there a way to fix it (it is innodb engine) without restoring the whole DB from backup? thank you;